# JPA Hibernate deleteAll(List<T> entities) not working as expected

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to batch delete n objects with JPA repository deleteAll(List entities), and it works. But at the end it produces n queries to the database instead of grouping elements by the batch size.

Expected behaviour:

- 20 entities to delete
- batch size 10
- queries to the database 2

Actual behaviour:

- 20 entities to delete
- batch size 10
- queries to the database 20

If I do the batch update saveAll(List entities) I am getting expected behaviour with 2 queries produced.

Comment: what is the query logged into the console?
And also enable statistics log and add that

Comment: You should use the method `deleteAllInBatch(List entities)` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

deleteAll(List entities) will delete all objects in one session, so the number of queries will be the n, grouped by the batch_size.

Answer (score 0):

Extend your repository from JpaRepository and try using `deleteAllInBatch(List entities);`

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but this is not answer to my question. That is the possible option, but I don't have control over it as batch size is not applicable (it will always produce 1 query to the DB).

Answer (score 0):

By default deleteAll not support for batch operations it will iterator each object and hibernate will do the deletion you can check in the console logs(`hibernate delete query`).

For the batch deletion you can use below method.
deleteAllInBatch();

Reference - https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html#deleteAllInBatch-java.lang.Iterable-